# Keeping the preceding zero's when returning chosen date and converting into Strings

Tags: android, string, sqlite, datepicker, int

I am following the tutorial/example of the date picker dialog [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) and it works fine.
The issue that i have is that i want to be able to place the date returned into an SQLite Database in a text format, however it seems that the preceding zero's on the date are being cut off when i convert the ints into strings e.g. 2013/09/07 becomes 2013/9/7, which makes it difficult to work with, how would i go about adding/keeping the preceding 0's??

many thanks in advance

here's the code i have for retrieving the date and converting into a string

```
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        String date = String.valueOf(year)+"/" + String.valueOf(month)+"/" + String.valueOf(day);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month, date);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String s = sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Works great many thanks, I had previously tried the SDF but without the preceding Calendar part so it didn't work, but now works great!